# How can I read a CSV with quoted commas as a flat file in BusinessObjects Data Services Designer?

Tags: csv, escaping, quotes, business-objects

I'm trying to get SAP BusinessObjects Data Services Designer 12.2.3.1 to read a CSV file that contains rows like:

```
"00501","P",0,0,"Nassau-Suffolk, NY","SUFFOLK"
```

The results I'm getting with column delimiter set to Comma, however, read that line as seven columns rather than six:

```
"00501"    "P"       0        0       "Nassau-Suffolk        NY"      "SUFFOLK"
```

What additional options do I need in order to read the file as-is, without external preprocessing? (If this isn't possible, please say so and I'll stop getting grey matter all over this nice brick wall. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Solution to load data with double quote:

[image: screenshot of settings]

Comment: Can you explain the solution in words? A screenshot can be a helpful addition, but it generally shouldn't be the only thing in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the **Text** delimiter to `"`.

> **Text:** Denotes the start and end of a text string. All characters (including those specified as column delimiters) between the first and second occurrence of this character is a single text string. The treatment of the row characters is defined by the "Row within text string" setting.